# Generate PDF Blank Page

Tags: fpdf

I'm using fpdf library and there's no output produce after I run the code.. What's the problem and how can I resolve it?

Note: It also produces no errors, so it's so hard to fix the bug

Comment: Are you sure the input is being read? Is there a log of some sort or verbose setting you can turn on?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599192/blank-output-pdf-using-fpdf-library-codeigniter Are these the same problems?

Comment: yes.. i use to test the code in localhost and it runs perfectly.. the $this->fpdf->OUTPUT('filename.pdf','I') is not also working.. what's the problem and how can I solve this?

Comment: can you post your code ?